# Не могу получить json при создании своего приложения в console.developers.google.com

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Создаю свое приложения в console.developers.google.com по [этому](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPkEN.png) видео. Интерфейс отличается, но я выполняю те же шаги что и человек с видео. На 05:51 у него загружается json, у меня ничего не загружается и кнопки такой нет. Я все таки создал приложение и без этого, а после пытался найти этот json, но не получилось.

По шагам с видео тут должен быть json, у меня нет:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут я просто нажимаю Done:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее перекидывает сюда:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как все таки получить мне json?

UPDATE:

Решил эту проблему тыкая куда только можно на протяжении нескольких часов...
Нужно пройтись по всем этим пунктам и там выполнить все шаги, просто понажимать на далее (на самом деле точно не знаю этого, нужно или нет, но после всего этого у меня только и получилось получить json):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И нажать на эту замечательную кнопку, она и отдаст json

UPDATE:

Я подумал что на этом все, даже в ответ записал... Но это не тот json который мне нужен, так я подумал по этой ошибке - `ValueError: ('Unexpected credentials type', None, 'Expected', 'service_account')`

На эту ошибку отвечают [здесь](https://coderoad.ru/38709324/-Unexpected-credentials-type-None-Expected-service_account-%D1%81-oauth2client), тут и говорится то, что это не тот json.

Answer (score 0):

Все таки все, теперь уже точно.
Сначала нужно тыкнуть сюда, на почту:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбрать меня KEY:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажать кнопку ADD KEY:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После - `Create new key > JSON`